# How to use the cloudformation wait command with cdk deploy?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

We had an error that occurred when two deploys were triggered pretty much simultaneously which in turn triggered an error:

```
Error [ValidationError]: Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:[stack] is in UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS state and can not be updated
```

So I found that you can set wait and stack-update-complete in cloudformation to wait before trying to update.

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/wait/stack-update-complete.html

But how am I to use it with the CDK deploy cli?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518054/how-to-wait-stack-to-complete-before-executing-code-in-aws-cdk help?

Comment: @kgiannakakis I don't think so. I want to wait to deploy if there is already a deployment in progress of the same stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in CDK. You can do it manually with the aws cli, as described in the link in your question.

`aws cloudformation wait stack-update-complete --stack-name MyStack && cdk deploy MyStack`

Comment: Aah ok. Didn't know cloudformation modified the stack. Thanks!

Comment: CDK code synthesizes a Cloudformation template, and Cloudformation is what's deploying the resources.

Comment: @Patrik given this restriction, if you add your CDK deployment to a pipeline, in its own stage, it will not trigger a second time until the first triggered one is complete. Manual deployment however can and will run into this situation often.