# How do I reference cross-stack resources in the same app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have an app that has two stacks, both within the same region/account. One of those stacks requires the ARN of a lambda that exists in the other stack. How do I reference this?

```js
// within stackA constructor
public StackA(Construct scope, String id, StackProps props) {
    SingletonFunction myLambda = SingletonFunction.Builder.create(this, "myLambda")
        // some code here
        .build()
    CfnOutput myLambdaArn = CfnOutput.Builder.create(this, "myLambdaArn")
        .exportName("myLambdaArn")
        .description("ARN of the lambda that I want to use in StackB")
        .value(myLambda.getFunctionArn())
        .build();
    
}

App app = new App();
Stack stackA = new StackA(app, "stackA", someAProps);    
Stack stackB = new StackB(app, "stackB", someBProps);
stackB.dependsOn(stackA);
```

How do pass the ARN into StackB?

Answer (score 31):

CDK's official documentation has a complete example for [sharing a S3 bucket between stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-s3-readme.html#sharing-buckets-between-stacks). I copied it below for quicker reference.

```js
/**
 * Stack that defines the bucket
 */
class Producer extends cdk.Stack {
  public readonly myBucket: s3.Bucket;

  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'MyBucket', {
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    });
    this.myBucket = bucket;
  }
}

interface ConsumerProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  userBucket: s3.IBucket;
}

/**
 * Stack that consumes the bucket
 */
class Consumer extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: ConsumerProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const user = new iam.User(this, 'MyUser');
    props.userBucket.grantReadWrite(user);
  }
}

const producer = new Producer(app, 'ProducerStack');
new Consumer(app, 'ConsumerStack', { userBucket: producer.myBucket });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Would not have found that otherwise, and the example in the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/resources.html#resource_stack) is pretty limited.

Answer (score 19):

You can access resources in a different stack, as long as they are in the same account and AWS Region. The following example defines the stack stack1, which defines an Amazon S3 bucket. Then it defines a second stack, stack2, which takes the bucket from stack1 as a constructor property.

```js
// Helper method to build an environment
static Environment makeEnv(String account, String region) {
    return Environment.builder().account(account).region(region)
            .build();
}

App app = new App();

Environment prod = makeEnv("123456789012", "us-east-1");

StackThatProvidesABucket stack1 = new StackThatProvidesABucket(app, "Stack1",
        StackProps.builder().env(prod).build());

// stack2 will take an argument "bucket"
StackThatExpectsABucket stack2 = new StackThatExpectsABucket(app, "Stack,",
        StackProps.builder().env(prod).build(), stack1.getBucket());
```

Comment: Nice, do you have any documentation regarding this implementation?

Comment: You can find it more detailed in the below AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/resources.html

Comment: I rather work with my example since i can import and export from other region\accounts as well, but good to know. thanks for sharing :)

Comment: where is stack1.getBucket defined?  Not defining it means we have to guess and sometimes we guess wrong.

Comment: Here's a post with a full example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57586393/856498

Comment: This answer is inadequate because it doesn't explain how stack1 gets a reference to the bucket in the first place. This is central to solving the problem and should be included in an accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

**Option 1:**

pass the data from Stack A to Stack B using the constructor :

You can extend `cdk.stack` and create a new class that will contain stackA.

In that stack, expose the relevant data you want by using `public XXX: string\number (etc)` ( See line 2 in the example).

Later, just pass this data into StackB constructor ( you can pass it using props as well).

**Working code snippet:**

**Stack A:**

```js
    export class StackA extends cdk.Stack {
        public YourKey: KEY_TYPE;
    
        constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps ) {
            super(scope, id, props);
    
            Code goes here...
    
            // Output the key 
            new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'KEY', { value: this.YourKey });
    
        }
    }
```

**Stack B:**

```js
export class StackB extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string,importedKey: KEY_TYPE, props: cdk.props) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        Code goes here...
        
        console.log(importedKey)

    }
}
```

**bin ts:**

```js
const importedKey = new StackA(app, 'id',props).YourKey;
new StackB(app, 'id',importedKey,props);
```

**Option 2:**

Sometimes it's just better to save this kind of stuff in the parameter store and read it from there.

More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ssm-readme.html).

Comment: Will this work please for cross-account deployments? e.g. How would I reference a resource like a Lambda defined within `Stack A` from within `Stack B`, if they were in 2 different accounts? I'm trying to do a deployment of `Stack B` with credentials for that account but getting an error that I need credentials for `Stack A` too.

Comment: This should work as with cross region\account as well.. can you sure the error?

Comment: Error looks like: "Need to perform AWS calls for account 111111111111, but no credentials found. Tried: default credentials", where I use credentials for account 222222222222 in order to deploy stack B. Related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26137203

Comment: where do you set the value of YourKey in Stack A?

Comment: @PaulS you can set it hard-coded or fill it using `this.YourKey`

Comment: @AmitBaranes when I try to pass the endpoint url of an apigateway to another stack/construct via `new cdk.CfnOutput(this, api.url, { value: this.apiUrl });` I always get `Cannot use tokens in construct ID: https://${Token[TOKEN.54]}.execute-api.${Token[AWS.Region.4]}.${Token[AWS.URLSuffix.1]}/${Token[TOKEN.72]}/` Did you encounter this problem as well?

Comment: @benito_h try - `cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'api', { value: this.apiUrl });`

Answer (score 8):

I found all of the answers to be on the right path, but none explained it fully and/or well. In this example, I'm passing a VPC from a VPC stack to an ECS cluster.

First, add a property to the originating stack. This property is set whenever the asset is created:

```js
export class VpcStack extends cdk.Stack {
    readonly vpc: Vpc;

    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
    
        // Here
        this.vpc = new Vpc(this, 'vpc', {
            maxAzs: 3,
            cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
        });
    });
}
```

Next, require this property as a parameter to the consuming stack:

```js
// Create an interface that extends cdk.StackProps
// The VPC property is added here
interface EcsClusterStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
    vpc: Vpc,
}

export class EcsClusterStack extends cdk.Stack {
    // Use your interface instead of the regular cdk.StackProps
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: EcsClusterStackProps) {  
        super(scope, id, props);
    
        // Use the passed-in VPC where you need it
        new Cluster(this, "myCluster", {
            capacity: {
                instanceType: InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.M6I, InstanceSize.LARGE)
            },
            clusterName: "myCluster",
            vpc: props.vpc,  // Here
        });
    }
}
```

Third, pass the reference in your app file:

```js
const app = new cdk.App();

// Create the VPC stack
const vpcStack = new VpcStack(app, 'vpc-stack', {
    env: { account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION },
});

// Pass the VPC directly to the consuming stack's constructor
const ecsClusterStack = new EcsClusterStack(app, 'ecs-cluster-stack', {
    vpc: vpcStack.vpc,  // Here
});
```

Hopefully this helps clarify some of the ambiguous areas.

Comment: A couple resources that helped me: [Bobby's blog](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cdk-share-resources-between-stacks) and the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-s3-readme.html#sharing-buckets-between-stacks)

Answer (score 1):

On Alien Attack  https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-alien-attack I created a class named ResourceAwareStack that extends Stack, and implements methods to add/get resources that can be shared between stacks. Take a look at it.

Comment: This may answer the question, but when the link becomes stale the answer becomes redundant. Can you add more detail so the answer becomes stand-alone without outside links...